# FOSUserBundle and save roles Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony

i need help to resolve problem with save roles. Now i to do in form with checkbox selected roles.

```
->add(
            'roles',
            ChoiceType::class,
            [
                'constraints' => new NotBlank(),
                'label' => 'TYPE',
                'choices' => $this->roles,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'required' => true,
            ]
        )
```

But me need with radio button, if i change multiple to false i have radio button, but than i don't know how resolve problem with roles string value, because fosuser expended array

In controller when handlerequest, catch error expected array string given

Comment: Try a datatransformer: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: can put example for this issue, i that i save from radio button role in string, transformed it to array for fosuserbundle